# Webbutton is not working in chrome in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

Webbutton is not working in chrome in asp.net application. It throws an error complaining about `SubmitTheData()` not defined.

The same code works for IE browser.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SubmitTheData is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (MTree.aspx:468:316)

When I see Developer Tool Source, It throws error

`<input onclick="SubmitTheData(this); __doPostBack('SelectAllButton','')" name="SelectAllButton" type="button" id="SelectAllButton" value="Select All" id="btn226705" class="EButton" title="Select All" /></cc1:WebButton>`

Is there any way to write this line of code in a way that it does not throw error

`strFunction = (parameters.Count > 0)? "SubmitTheData(this" + GetParam() +");":"SubmitTheData(this);"; } return strFunction;`

```
<cc1:WebButton ID="SelectAllButton" runat="server"></cc1:WebButton>
                
                
                
WebButton.cs        
                
     private string GetFunction()
    {
        string strFunction = string.Empty;
        
        if (this.function != string.Empty )
        {
            strFunction = this.function ;
        }
        else
        {
            strFunction = (parameters.Count > 0)? "SubmitTheData(this" + GetParam() +");":"SubmitTheData(this);";
        }
        return strFunction;
    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {                   
        this.Attributes.Add("onclick",GetFunction().ToString());            
        base.Render (writer);           
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: `<cc1:WebButton>` is not a standard control in ASP.NET WebForms, it is a custom control loaded from a third-party library you're using: look for `tagPrefix="cc1"` in your `web.config` file to get the assembly name. You will need to contact the author of that library for assistance.

Comment: @Dai, this throws an error `strFunction = (parameters.Count > 0)? "SubmitTheData(this" + GetParam() +");":"SubmitTheData(this);";`. How to write this in a wat that it does not throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see VERY but VERY little reason to have your custom control code "inject" a click event.

Why not have your user control just use a simple and standard asp.net button, and a simple and standard button click for that button?

But, it would HUGE help if you posted the markup for that user control. Without that markup, it is BEYOND hard to guess and see what markup you have for that user control.

As a general rule, you can build and design the user control with standard markup.

The ONLY difficult part becomes if  you want button click code in the UC to trigger code on the current web page as opposed to code for your user control.

Also, YOU LEFT OUT the page markup for where you dropped the UC code in. I mean, sure, all nice and warm and fuzzy to provide the output debug browser code as to what the UC renders as - and after making all that effort, you THEN for some beyond ASTOUNDING reason, leave out the markup on the page where you dropped in that UC control? We don't need the whole page of original markup, but you SURE as the heck want to share AT LEAST "some" of the markup for that UC control  you have. (why leave that out - I am truly wondering why???).

However, there is (should be) ZERO need to use the "render" event here to add the on-click event - a VERY bad idea unless all other roads and possibilities have been exhausted.

So, post the main page markup - at least a wee bit where you dropped in your UC.

And of course, post all the code AND ALSO the markup you have for your UC.